# Schema XSD: how to enumerate an attribute and a related element value

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes, enumeration

I have an XSD that works today for validating a special kind of element we have of type "Option". As an example, here is the current definition of an element called "operation":

```
<xsd:element name="operation" type="Option" minOccurs="0"/>
```

And here is the definition of type Option:

```
 <xsd:complexType name="Option">
  <xsd:simpleContent>
   <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:attribute name="option" type="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:simpleContent>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

So this element might be left out or might appear once, and it typically looks something like this:

Insert

I would like to make our XSD more strict while at the same time including information for vendors who get the XSD to enumerate the possible values for the option attribute, the possible (related/translated) values for the element itself, and what default is assumed if the element is missing entirely. So if the only two values for the option attribute are "I" and "U" and the actual element value should be either "Insert" or "Update" (or blank, actually), and the default value if the element is missing entirely is "U"/Update, I would like to write my XSD for this element to include all that information and to successfully validate any of the following four options:

```
<operation option="U"/>
<operation option="I"/>
<operation option="U">Update</operation>
<operation option="I">Insert</operation>
```

It should also successfully validate the document if this element is missing entirely. It should NOT validate successfully if the element is present but the option attribute is missing, if it is anything other than "U" or "I". It also shouldn't validate successfully if the element is present and the text value for the element is present but is anything other than "Update" or "Insert". Furthermore, it shouldn't validate if the option attribute is "U" but the text for the element reads "Insert" or vice versa ("I" and "Update"). As if all that isn't bad enough, I'm hoping to avoid defining new types, because I am going to be doing this for several data types of type Option, and all of these value lists aren't global--I'm going to want to include them as part of the each element definition if possible.

So far, I have only made it as far as making the "option" attribute be required and be an enumeration:

```
   <xsd:element name="operation" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
       <xsd:attribute name="option" use="required">
        <xsd:simpleType>
         <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:enumeration value="I"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="U"/>
         </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
       </xsd:attribute>
      </xsd:extension>
     </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
```

I can't specify a default value for the option attribute when I make the attribute required. But my need for a default is to specify that if the element is missing entirely, it should be treated as though Update were in the document.

Any XSD experts out there that can suggest the best way to meet all these goals? If I can't do it without defining new types by name outside of the actual element definition, I suppose I can try to do that, but it will be harder to avoid name collisions and the enumeration information would end up too far from the element definition itself, so I'd like to avoid that need if I can.

Answer (score 0):

> Furthermore, it shouldn't validate if the option attribute is "U" but the text for the element reads "Insert" or vice versa ("I" and "Update")

This is known as a co-occurrence constraint and it requires XSD 1.1 (which not all commonly-used schema processors support).

It can be expressed in XSD 1.1 either with assertions, for example

```
<xs:assert test="(@option='U' and .='Update') or
                 (@option='I' and .='Insert') or
                 ..."/>
```

or with conditional type assignment (aka "type alternatives") where the type of the element is defined to be conditional on the value of one of the element's attributes.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
. . .
<!-- @ExtendedAttribute schema -->
<xsd:element name="ExtendedAttributes" minOccurs="0">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>The collection of extended attribute (custom field) definitions associated with the project.</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="ExtendedAttribute" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>Each of the individual entries in the extended attributes definition collection.  There are no limits to the number of children that may appear, but Project only understands Flag1-Flag10, etc.  There must be at least one ExtendedAttribute in each ExtendedAttributes collection.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="FieldID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>This corresponds to the PID of the custom field.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="FieldName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The name of the custom field.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="CFType" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The custom field type. Values are: 0=Cost, 1=Date, 2=Duration, 3=Finish, 4=Flag, 5=Number, 6=Start, 7=Text.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                  <xsd:enumeration value="0" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="1" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="2" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="3" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="4" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="5" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="6" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="7" />
                </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Guid" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The GUID of the custom field.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ElemType" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Specifies whether the extended attribute is associated with a task, a resource, or an assignment. Values are: 20=Task, 21=Resource, 22=Calendar, 23=Assignment.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                  <xsd:enumeration value="20" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="21" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="22" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="23" />
                </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="MaxMultiValues" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Specifies the maximum number of values you can set in a picklist.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="UserDef" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Specifies whether the custom field is user-defined.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Alias" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The alias of the custom field.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                  <xsd:maxLength value="50" />
                </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="SecondaryPID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The secondary PID of the custom field.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="AutoRollDown" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Specifies whether automatic rolldown to assignments is enabled.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="DefaultGuid" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Specifies the GUID of the default lookup table entry.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Ltuid" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The GUID of the lookup table associated with the custom field.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="PhoneticAlias" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The phonetic pronunciation of the alias of the custom field.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                  <xsd:maxLength value="50" />
                </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="RollupType" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>How rollups are calculated. Values are: 0=Maximum (OR for flag fields), 1=Minimum (AND for flag fields), 2=Count all, 3=Sum, 4=Average, 5=Average First Sublevel, 6=Count First Sublevel, 7=Count Nonsummaries.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                  <xsd:enumeration value="0" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="1" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="2" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="3" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="4" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="5" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="6" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="7" />
                </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="CalculationType" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Whether rollups are calculated for task and group summary rows. Values are: 0=None, 1=Rollup, 2=Calculation.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                  <xsd:enumeration value="0" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="1" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="2" />
                </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Formula" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The formula that Microsoft Project uses to populate the custom task field.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="RestrictValues" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>If RestrictValues=True then only values in the list are allowed in the file.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ValuelistSortOrder" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>How value lists are sorted. Values are: 0=Descending, 1=Ascending.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                  <xsd:enumeration value="0" />
                  <xsd:enumeration value="1" />
                </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="AppendNewValues" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>If AppendNewValues=True then any new values added in a project are automatically appended to the list.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Default" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>This points to the default value in the list.  Not present if no default is set.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ValueList" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>When values of extended attributes are specified as properties of elements in the schema, they can be specified either by values or by references to the values contained in this list.  Applications can assume ordering of the list by ordering specified here.</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="Value" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                      <xsd:documentation>The values that make up the value list.</xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:complexType>
                      <xsd:all>
                        <xsd:element name="ID" type="xsd:integer">
                          <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>Unique ID of value across the project.</xsd:documentation>
                          </xsd:annotation>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                          <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>The actual value.</xsd:documentation>
                          </xsd:annotation>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                          <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>The description of the value in the list.</xsd:documentation>
                          </xsd:annotation>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="Phonetic" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                          <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>Phonetic information for custom field names.</xsd:documentation>
                          </xsd:annotation>
                        </xsd:element>
                      </xsd:all>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                  </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The "answer" appears to be completely unrelated to the question.